# How to call async Task within IAsyncResult method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, iasyncresult

I have an existing method with return type `IAsyncResult` from older code, how can I call an async Task from within this method? For example:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginXXX()
{
    // I want to call my async Task here, but it cannot compile like this:
    var value = await DoMyTaskAsync();
    DoSomethingWithValue(value);

    // existing code
    return new SomeOtherAsyncResult();
}
```

Edit: The solution would preferably not have to refactor the method signature, that would involve work beyond the scope.

Comment: Why are you using IAsyncResult over a standard Task?

Comment: Because I have to work with legacy code, and the work required to refactor up the call stack is far beyond scope.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Task` is derived from `IAsyncResult`,

```
public class Task : IThreadPoolWorkItem, IAsyncResult, IDisposable ...
```

Wrap the refactored code in a `Task.Run` In order to maintain the current API and still be able to use `async-await`

```
public IAsyncResult BeginXXX() {        
    return Task.Run(async () => {
        var value = await DoMyTaskAsync(); // I want to call my async Task here
        DoSomethingWithValue(value);

        // existing code
        return new SomeOtherAsyncResult();
    });
}
```

this should work for the scope of shown example.

I highly suggest this only be a temporary fix as this could potentially cause deadlocks up the stack with the mixing of async and blocking calls.

This code and the code that depends on it should eventually be refactored to follow the recommendations of the common documentation provided for asynchronous code.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an existing method with return type IAsyncResult from older code, how can I call an async Task from within this method?

The answer is in the [TAP interop documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#from-tap-to-apm). Essentially you return a `TaskCompletionSource<T>.Task`.

Here's some [helpers from my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/8a73d0467d40ca41f9f9cf827c7a35702243abb8/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/Interop/ApmAsyncFactory.cs) that make this much easier:

```
public static IAsyncResult ToBegin<TResult>(Task<TResult> task, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>(state, TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
  var oldContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  SynchronizationContext.Current = null;
  try
  {
    CompleteAsync(task, callback, tcs);
  }
  finally
  {
    SynchronizationContext.Current = oldContext;
  }
  return tcs.Task;
}

// `async void` is on purpose, to raise `callback` exceptions directly on the thread pool.
private static async void CompleteAsync<TResult>(Task<TResult> task, AsyncCallback callback, TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs)
{
  try
  {
    tcs.TrySetResult(await task.ConfigureAwait(false));
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
  {
    tcs.TrySetCanceled(ex.CancellationToken);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    tcs.TrySetException(ex);
  }
  finally
  {
    callback?.Invoke(tcs.Task);
  }
}

public static TResult ToEnd<TResult>(IAsyncResult asyncResult) =>
    ((Task<TResult>)asyncResult).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Note that the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is necessary to have the proper semantics for your `state` argument.

With these, your implementation can look like:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginXXX(...rest, AsyncCallback callback, object state) =>
    XXXAsync(...rest).ToBegin(callback, state);
public EndXXX(IAsyncResult asyncResult) => TaskExtensions.ToEnd<MyResult>(asyncResult);

public async Task<MyResult> XXXAsync(...rest)
{
  var value = await DoMyTaskAsync();
  DoSomethingWithValue(value);
  return myResult;
}
```

Note that this assumes you're going to translate everything at this level into `async`/`await` and get rid of the `new SomeOtherAsyncResult`. However, if you have a lower-level `IAsyncResult`-based API that you are not ready to convert to `async`/`await` and that you still need to call, then your `XXXAsync` method can use [TAP-over-APM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#from-apm-to-tap):

```
public async Task<MyResult> XXXAsync(...rest)
{
  var value = await DoMyTaskAsync();
  DoSomethingWithValue(value);
  return await TaskFactory.FromAsync(BeginOtherAsyncResult, EndOtherAsyncResult,
      ...restOtherAsyncResultArgs, null);
}
```

In this case you end up with APM-over-TAP (to keep your `BeginXXX` interface) and TAP-over-APM (to continue using the `OtherAsyncResult` interface), with your TAP method sandwiched between (`XXXAsync`).

Answer (score -1):

This is a common problem. You solve this using `TaskCompletionSource`.

Let's say you have a legacy class and it has the old-style async methods `BeginBar` and `EndBar`. The `BeginBar` accepts an `AsyncCallback` delegate.

```
public Task<int> Foo()
{
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    someLegacyClass.BeginBar( x => source.TrySetResult(someLegacyClass.EndBar(x)); }
    return source.Task;
}
```

See [interop with other asynchronous patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types)

Comment: This solution seems like it would require refactoring of the upper call stack, which is far beyond the scope in my scenario

Comment: Oh I see. So you want to be able to call and await an async method from inside a method that is not async?

Comment: @JohnWu Yes, I wish to have solution that can call async tasks within the IAsyncResult method without having to refactor the IAsyncResult method signature.

Answer (score -1):

You "could" ignore every good in [Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) when calling `DoMyTaskAsync` function and do this:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginXXX()
{
    // I want to call my async Task here, but it cannot compile like this:
    var value = DoMyTaskAsync().Result;
    DoSomethingWithValue(value);

    // existing code
    return new SomeOtherAsyncResult();
}
```

Or, you could read about what `async` does to a function. All `DoMyTaskAsync` does really, if you don't use `await` when calling it, is that it's returning a `Task<T>` instance.

You can operate a `Task` instance normally without relying on `await`. Have a read on [Task-based Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: Their requirements aren't to make the method asynchronous, it's just to change the API of how it reports its *asynchronous* result to the caller.

Answer (score -3):

You're missing an `async` keyword in your function definition.
You'll also need to return a `Task<T>`.

Try something like this:

```
public async Task<IAsyncResult> BeginXXX()
{
    await DoMyTaskAsync();

    // the rest of your code
}
```